# GPROF output file error with NO info presented

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gnu, gprof

### Problem Description

I was trying to get a gprof file from the code below:

```
//test.cpp
#include<stdio.h>
void func1() {
    printf("Inside func1");
    for(int i = 1;i<0xffffffff;i++);
}
void func2() {
    printf("Inside func2");
    for(int i = 1;i<0xffffffaa;i++);
}
int main() {
    printf("Inside main()");
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++);
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

And I ran these commands in the shell:

```
> g++ test.cpp -o test -pg
> ./test
Inside main()
Inside func1 
Inside func2 
> gprof -b test gmon.out > rep
```

However, In the file "rep", I didnt find the program running detail inside.

Here is the "rep" file:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    


            Call graph


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) no time propagated

index % time    self  children    called     name


Index by function name
```

I've googled it on the Internet but not meeting the similar problem. Could somebody tell how to solve this?

### Software Version

g++ (GCC) 7.1.1 20170630

GNU gprof (GNU Binutils) 2.28.0.20170506

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run the program, does it print the output you expected? Can you please copy-paste the entire "session" including output from the program, and add it to the question?

Comment: @Some programmer dude I've changed the problem description. Is it complete? Thank you!